# What is the general purpose of concealment algorithms introduced in…?

Tags: symmetric, authenticated-encryption, commitments

What is the general purpose of concealment algorithms introduced in https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/050.pdf?

Comment: This is not even a question, try to actually formulate a question instead of "blah blah.. introduced in".

Answer (score 1):

The purpose seems to be offering an interesting new building block for authenticated encryption.

They split a message into a long *hider* $h$ and a short *binder* $b$ with the following properties:

1. $h$ reveals no information about $m$
2. $h$ and $b$ allow recovering $m$
3. There is only one $h$ with which $b$ can be used to recover $m$

They use this functionality to extend an authenticated encryption scheme that works only on short messages to one on long messages. One uses the given authenticated encryption scheme $\mathcal{AE}$ to encrypt the shorter binder $b$ and gets authenticated encryption of the entire $m$ by the properties above.

Specifically,

1. $h$ can be public because it reveals nothing about $m$
2. After decrypting $\mathcal{AE}(b)$ the receiver can reconstruct $m$ using $h$
3. The message must be authentic because there is only one $h$ which will work with $b$

They also use it to build Remotely Keyed Authenticated Encryption.

> To summarize, we show that concealments are very natural cryptographic gadgets, and can be efficiently
>   built from standard assumptions. In particular, they give an efficient way to implement “long” authenticated
>   encryption from a “short” one. Finally, we describe a powerful application of concealments and our ampli-
>   fication technique to the problem of
>   RKAE
>   , which deserves a separate introduction.

This RKAE has pretty much exactly the goal they achieve, to split authenticated encryption between something like a fast PC and a slow smartcard where the key is only used on the smartcard but it only needs to encrypt small messages.